# RSS feed of top weekly posts

Tags: support, feed

I'm looking for a way to create or subscribe to a particular RSS feed of a given Stack Exchange. I'd like to subscribe to an RSS feed on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) for the top voted posts each week. The URL I'd like to get an RSS feed from is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/?tab=week). Is this possible?

Comment: @ColeJohnson, just because something isn't popular, you assume it isn't useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest this RSS link:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/feeds/week

The way I came up with the link is via Stack Overflow - when I visit [Stack Overflow's weekly page](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=week), I see a related RSS feed at the bottom of the page: https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/week. I simply took this Stack Overflow feed link and adjusted it for the stats site.

NOTE that for some reason the questions in the RSS feed do not match up with the questions in the weekly page (for either site). That may be another meta question....

Answer (score 2):

Would this give you what you want: https://stats.stackexchange.com/feeds/hot

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, this is not what I am looking for. I'm not sure how 'hot' is calculated, but many of the questions in this feed have no votes. Specifically, I'm looking for some way to subscribe to feeds that receive the most number of up votes for a given week.

Comment: I think hot is based on votes and other activity (eg comments and views) so yeah - not *quite* what you're looking for...